# date picker not showing

Tags: codeigniter, datepicker

I tried a simple datepicker in my codeigniter page but somehow it's not showing datepicker.

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
```

my html code is,

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pickup Date" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="formfield_text hasDatepicker">
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Have you included jQuery and jQuery UI? What is the error? Currently, this question does not provide enough detail to answer the question. For example, provide any error logs in the console and post your _full_ HTML. For more information on asking questions on [so], see [ask].

Comment: check the id of the datepicker is "datepicker" ?

Comment: <input type="text" placeholder="Pickup Date" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="formfield_text hasDatepicker">

Comment: does datepicker work with ci??

Comment: @chirag yes it works with ci

Comment: i had used a simple datepicker code but getting no error in console as well

Comment: is it all codes are on the same view page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your html code,

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pickup Date" id="datepicker"  name="datepicker" class="formfield_text">
```

This works. The problem is that you can not use class `hasDatepicker`. Remove it and try.